# How does one add support for Take(int) to Dynamic Linq?

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

We are currently developing a website which uses dynamic linq queries with embedded linq statements. By which I mean:

`bla.OrderBy("Thing.OrderBy(ExpirationDate).Select(ExpirationDate)")`

Might not be entirely valid syntax but you get the idea, dynamic linq statements inside of dynamic linq statements.

Now I'm trying to use `Take` in one of those statements and I get the following exception:

> No generic method 'Take' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is
>   compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type
>   arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.`

So far I've added four methods to the `DynamicQueryable` class in the "DynamicLinq" file which I took from the examples directory. Namely the following:

```
public static IQueryable Take(this IQueryable source, int count)
public static IQueryable<T> Take<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int count)
public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
public static IEnumerable Take(this IEnumerable source, int count)
```

I also added three methods to `IEnumerableSignatures`, namely:

```
void Take();
void Take(int count);
void Take(object selector);
```

I am aware I probably don't need two of those, but I go desperate ;)

The exception originates from the method `ParseAggregate` which looks like:

```
Expression ParseAggregate(Expression instance, Type elementType, string methodName, int errorPos)
{
    ParameterExpression outerIt = it;
    ParameterExpression innerIt = Expression.Parameter(elementType, "");
    it = innerIt;
    Expression[] args = ParseArgumentList();
    it = outerIt;
    MethodBase signature;
    if (FindMethod(typeof(IEnumerableSignatures), methodName, false, args, out signature) != 1)
        throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.NoApplicableAggregate, methodName);
    Type[] typeArgs;
    if (signature.Name == "Min" || signature.Name == "Max"
        || signature.Name == "OrderBy" || signature.Name == "OrderByDescending" || signature.Name == "Select" || signature.Name == "SelectMany")
    {
        typeArgs = new[] { elementType, args[0].Type };

        // HACK: If it's a SelectMany clause, we need the type held by the collection, not the type of the collection itself
        if (signature.Name == "SelectMany")
            typeArgs[1] = args[0].Type.UnderlyingSystemType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
    else
    {
        typeArgs = new Type[] { elementType };
    }

    if (args.Length == 0)
        args = new Expression[] { instance };
    else
        args = new Expression[] { instance, Expression.Lambda(args[0], innerIt) };

    return Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), signature.Name, typeArgs, args);
}
```

The exception is thrown at the call to `Expression.Call` and the values for the parameters are `"Take"`, `typeof(DateTime)` and the last parameter values consists of an array with the expression on which Take is used and the value passed to Take (1, in this case).
Adding `"Take"` to the IF statement does not make any difference, the same exception if thrown even though a different value for `typeArgs` is passed.

Does anyone have any tips or tricks I can try? Or is there a special version of Dynamic Linq which has this built in?

Comment: Seems the existing logic for building `typeArgs` doesn't work for your usage, you'll have to add an `else if`.

Comment: What do you suggest I put in the `else if` block?